# Android notification doesn't work properly

Tags: android, notifications, timepicker

I'm trying to send a notification at a specific time,set by the user via `TimePicker`.
When i run my app the first Time , it works, but if I change the time of the notification my app send it immediately. I can't figure out why.

**MainActivity code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pkg=getPackageName();

    //Intent openPage1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Impostazioni.class);
    //startService(new Intent(this, serviceNot.class));

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , serviceNot.class);     
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("hour",MODE_PRIVATE);
    notificaH = sharedPref.getInt("hour", 9);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefS = getSharedPreferences("second",MODE_PRIVATE);
    notificaS = sharedPrefS.getInt("second", 10);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, notifyH);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, notifyS);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    long time=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    if(time<System.currentTimeMillis())
    {
        time=time+AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
    }

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours
```

**Settings code:**

```
public class Impostazioni extends ActionBarActivity 
{

 private Switch mySwitch;
 private Switch Sound;
 private TextView ViewOra;
 private Button btnSetOra;
 int ora;
 int minuti;
 static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID=0;
 public TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
 int notifyH=9;
 int notifyS=00;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_impostazioni);
    mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
    Sound = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.Switch01);
    ViewOra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ViewOra);
    btnSetOra = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnImpostaOra);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("hour",MODE_PRIVATE);
    notificaH = sharedPref.getInt("hour", 8);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefS = getSharedPreferences("second",MODE_PRIVATE);
    notificaS = sharedPrefS.getInt("second", 01);

    ViewOra.setText( notifyH + ":" + notifyS);  
    btnSetOra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Impostazioni.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    ViewOra.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);

                    notifyH=selectedHour;
                    notifyS=selectedMinute;

                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("hour",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
                    prefEditor.putInt("hour",notifyH);
                    prefEditor.commit();
                    SharedPreferences sharedPrefS = getSharedPreferences("second",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditorS = sharedPrefS.edit();
                    prefEditorS.putInt("second",notifyS);
                    prefEditorS.commit();

                }
            }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: check that what time is set in alarm manager try to debug also show code of your for service when it is wake up

Comment: Your issue implies that the current time is used to fire the notification. I'm guessing the time isn't passed to the firer of the notification properly? You should be able to see this if you use the debugger in the OnTimeSet method. It's a lot of code, you might want to break it down into smaller methods so you can find the problem much faster and have better reusability later.